# achieving a responsive Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am developing the front end for a new project of mine. And I am using a combination of custom CSS & bootstrap to achieve a responsive interface. The width is currently responsive & is resizing accordingly with the browser.

I now need to achieve the same but for the **HEIGHT** specifically.  Having a bit of troubles & running into a roadblock in doing this at the moment. Hopefully I may find some help here.

The specific elements I am trying to target are the 'Features' & 'Video-placeholder' elements on the page.  I would like to set it's height to expand with the page's size, so all elements on the interface remain proportional regardless of the browsers size.

See the design here on codepen: [Interface design](https://codepen.io/username-reserved/pen/jOYOxBg)

Code here as well:

```css
main > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #F8F8F8 !important;
}

nav {
  height: 85px;
  background-color: #FFF !important;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #DDD;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #ececec;
  padding: 0px 110px 0px 94px !important;
}


input  /* Hidden file input */
{
opacity:0.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
display: none;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  border: transparent;
}
 
#upld-button {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #B02BF4;
    border-color: #B02BF4;
    border-radius: 5em;
    padding: 10px 29px 14px 29px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: -16px;
}

#upld-button:hover {
  background: #9E41CE !important;
}

main {
  overflow: scroll;
}

#mid-section {
  margin: 126px 5% 2% 5%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#features {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 29%;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#files-dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
    background-color: #B02BF4;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

#files-dropdown:hover {
  background: #9E41CE;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  padding: 16px 40px 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  
}

li {
  padding: 36px 0 0 0;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #767575;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

#video-placeholder {
  min-width: 70%;
  height: 465px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-left: 4%;
}

#video-controls-container {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 310px 26px 6px;
  padding: 0px;
}

button.controls {
  color: #414040;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 1px #B02BF4;
  border-radius: 5em;
  margin: 0 6px 0px 0px;
  padding: 6px 26px;
}

button.controls:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #B02BF4;
  border: solid 1px #B02BF4;
}

footer {
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 79px;
  border-top: solid 1px #DDD;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #ECECEC;
  padding: 0px 61px 0px 61px;
}

#scrub-bar-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 19px 46px 29px 46px;
}

#play-button {
  background: #B02BF4 !important;
  border-color: #B02BF4 !important;
  color: #FFF !important;
}

#play-button:hover {
  background-color: #AA00FFA9 !important;
}

#scrub-bar { 
  background:#F4F4F4;
  margin: 0px 35px 0px 35px;
  padding: 0px 440px 9px 675px;
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 26px;
}

#placeholder {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #B02BF4;
  border-color: #B02BF4;
  border-radius: 5em;
  padding: 6px 29px 10px 29px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-block;
}

#placeholder:hover {
  background-color: #AA00FFA9 !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #B02BF4;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en" class = "h-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name = "description" content = "">
    <meta name = "author" content = "author">
    <title>Interface</title>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body class = "">
    
<header>
  
  <nav class = "navbar navbar-expand fixed-top">
    <div class = "container-fluid">
      <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#" style = "padding-top: 0px;">logo</a>

      </button>
      <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "navbarCollapse">
        <span class = "navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
        </span>
        <form class = "d-flex">
          <button id = "upld-button" onclick = "document.getElementById('file-input').click()"><input id = "file-input" type = "file" name = "file-upld" >UPLOAD</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>


<main class = "flex-shrink-0">
  <div id = "mid-section">
    <div id = "features">
      <div id = "files-dropdown"><span style="color: #FFF;">File(s)</span></div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-gear" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M8 4.754a3.246 3.246 0 1 0 0 6.492 3.246 3.246 0 0 0 0-6.492zM5.754 8a2.246 2.246 0 1 1 4.492 0 2.246 2.246 0 0 1-4.492 0z"/>
          <path d="M9.796 1.343c-.527-1.79-3.065-1.79-3.592 0l-.094.319a.873.873 0 0 1-1.255.52l-.292-.16c-1.64-.892-3.433.902-2.54 2.541l.159.292a.873.873 0 0 1-.52 1.255l-.319.094c-1.79.527-1.79 3.065 0 3.592l.319.094a.873.873 0 0 1 .52 1.255l-.16.292c-.892 1.64.901 3.434 2.541 2.54l.292-.159a.873.873 0 0 1 1.255.52l.094.319c.527 1.79 3.065 1.79 3.592 0l.094-.319a.873.873 0 0 1 1.255-.52l.292.16c1.64.893 3.434-.902 2.54-2.541l-.159-.292a.873.873 0 0 1 .52-1.255l.319-.094c1.79-.527 1.79-3.065 0-3.592l-.319-.094a.873.873 0 0 1-.52-1.255l.16-.292c.893-1.64-.902-3.433-2.541-2.54l-.292.159a.873.873 0 0 1-1.255-.52l-.094-.319zm-2.633.283c.246-.835 1.428-.835 1.674 0l.094.319a1.873 1.873 0 0 0 2.693 1.115l.291-.16c.764-.415 1.6.42 1.184 1.185l-.159.292a1.873 1.873 0 0 0 1.116 2.692l.318.094c.835.246.835 1.428 0 1.674l-.319.094a1.873 1.873 0 0 0-1.115 2.693l.16.291c.415.764-.42 1.6-1.185 1.184l-.291-.159a1.873 1.873 0 0 0-2.693 1.116l-.094.318c-.246.835-1.428.835-1.674 0l-.094-.319a1.873 1.873 0 0 0-2.692-1.115l-.292.16c-.764.415-1.6-.42-1.184-1.185l.159-.291A1.873 1.873 0 0 0 1.945 8.93l-.319-.094c-.835-.246-.835-1.428 0-1.674l.319-.094A1.873 1.873 0 0 0 3.06 4.377l-.16-.292c-.415-.764.42-1.6 1.185-1.184l.292.159a1.873 1.873 0 0 0 2.692-1.115l.094-.319z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-slash-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
          <path d="M11.354 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chat-right-text" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M2 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v8a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h9.586a2 2 0 0 1 1.414.586l2 2V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2zm12-1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12.793a.5.5 0 0 1-.854.353l-2.853-2.853a1 1 0 0 0-.707-.293H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12z"/>
          <path d="M3 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h9a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3 6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h9a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-9A.5.5 0 0 1 3 6zm0 2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-sticky" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M2.5 1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h6.086a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.06-.44l4.915-4.914A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 15 8.586V2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 13.5 1h-11zM2 2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V8H9.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 8 9.5V14H2.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11zm7 11.293V9.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4.293L9 13.793z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-circle-half" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1v14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 1 8 0a8 8 0 0 1 0 16z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <span id = "video-placeholder">
      
    </span>
    </div>

    <!--<div id = "video-controls-container">
      <button class = "controls">Skip backwards</button> <button class = "controls">skip forwards</button> <button class = "controls">Control</button> <button class = "controls">Control</button>
      </div>-->
</main>


<footer class = "navbar navbar-expand fixed-bottom">
  <div class = "container-fluid">
    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-outline-primary" id = "play-button">Play video</button>

    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "navbarCollapse">
      <span class = "navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0" id = "">
        <!--<div id = "scrub-bar">
        </div>-->
      </span>
      <form class = "d-flex">
        <button id = "placeholder">Trim</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

    <script src = "Interface/javascript/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of percent heights and display flex to shrink the page UI with browser window height, check below sample in full page view and resize your browser window.

```css
main > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: #F8F8F8 !important;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #FFF !important;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #DDD;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px #ececec;
  padding: 0px 110px 0px 94px !important;
}


input  /* Hidden file input */
{
opacity:0.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
display: none;
  height: 2vh;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  border: transparent;
  padding: 1vh 2vw;
  font-size: 4vh;
}
 
#upld-button {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #B02BF4;
    border-color: #B02BF4;
    border-radius: 5em;
    padding: 1vh 2vw;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: -16px;
  font-size: 4vh;
}

#upld-button:hover {
  background: #9E41CE !important;
}

main {
  overflow: scroll;
  
}

#mid-section {
  margin: 5%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

#features {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 29%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

#files-dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2vh;
    background-color: #B02BF4;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

#files-dropdown:hover {
  background: #9E41CE;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  padding: 16px 40px 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #767575;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

#video-placeholder {
  min-width: 70%;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-left: 4%;
}

#video-controls-container {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 310px 26px 6px;
  padding: 0px;
}

button.controls {
  color: #414040;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: solid 1px #B02BF4;
  border-radius: 5em;
  margin: 0 6px 0px 0px;
  padding: 6px 26px;
}

button.controls:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #B02BF4;
  border: solid 1px #B02BF4;
}

footer {
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 79px;
  border-top: solid 1px #DDD;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #ECECEC;
  padding: 0px 61px 0px 61px;
  height: 10vh;
}

#scrub-bar-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 19px 46px 29px 46px;
}

#play-button {
  background: #B02BF4 !important;
  border-color: #B02BF4 !important;
  color: #FFF !important;
}

#play-button:hover {
  background-color: #AA00FFA9 !important;
}

#scrub-bar { 
  background:#F4F4F4;
  margin: 0px 35px 0px 35px;
  padding: 0px 440px 9px 675px;
  display: inline;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 26px;
}

#placeholder {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #B02BF4;
  border-color: #B02BF4;
  border-radius: 5em;
  padding: 6px 29px 10px 29px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-block;
}

#placeholder:hover {
  background-color: #AA00FFA9 !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #B02BF4;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en" class = "h-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name = "description" content = "">
    <meta name = "author" content = "author">
    <title>Interface</title>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body class = "">
    
<header>
  
  <nav class = "navbar navbar-expand fixed-top">
    <div class = "container-fluid">
      <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#" style = "padding-top: 0px;">logo</a>

      </button>
      <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "navbarCollapse">
        <span class = "navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
        </span>
        <form class = "d-flex">
          <button id = "upld-button" onclick = "document.getElementById('file-input').click()"><input id = "file-input" type = "file" name = "file-upld" >UPLOAD</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>


<main class = "d-flex flex-grow-1">
  <div id = "mid-section">
    <div id = "features">
      <div id = "files-dropdown"><span style="color: #FFF;">File(s)</span></div>
      <ul class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1">
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-gear" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M8 4.754a3.246 3.246 0 1 0 0 6.492 3.246 3.246 0 0 0 0-6.492zM5.754 8a2.246 2.246 0 1 1 4.492 0 2.246 2.246 0 0 1-4.492 0z"/>
          <path d="M9.796 1.343c-.527-1.79-3.065-1.79-3.592 0l-.094.319a.873.873 0 0 1-1.255.52l-.292-.16c-1.64-.892-3.433.902-2.54 2.541l.159.292a.873.873 0 0 1-.52 1.255l-.319.094c-1.79.527-1.79 3.065 0 3.592l.319.094a.873.873 0 0 1 .52 1.255l-.16.292c-.892 1.64.901 3.434 2.541 2.54l.292-.159a.873.873 0 0 1 1.255.52l.094.319c.527 1.79 3.065 1.79 3.592 0l.094-.319a.873.873 0 0 1 1.255-.52l.292.16c1.64.893 3.434-.902 2.54-2.541l-.159-.292a.873.873 0 0 1 .52-1.255l.319-.094c1.79-.527 1.79-3.065 0-3.592l-.319-.094a.873.873 0 0 1-.52-1.255l.16-.292c.893-1.64-.902-3.433-2.541-2.54l-.292.159a.873.873 0 0 1-1.255-.52l-.094-.319zm-2.633.283c.246-.835 1.428-.835 1.674 0l.094.319a1.873 1.873 0 0 0 2.693 1.115l.291-.16c.764-.415 1.6.42 1.184 1.185l-.159.292a1.873 1.873 0 0 0 1.116 2.692l.318.094c.835.246.835 1.428 0 1.674l-.319.094a1.873 1.873 0 0 0-1.115 2.693l.16.291c.415.764-.42 1.6-1.185 1.184l-.291-.159a1.873 1.873 0 0 0-2.693 1.116l-.094.318c-.246.835-1.428.835-1.674 0l-.094-.319a1.873 1.873 0 0 0-2.692-1.115l-.292.16c-.764.415-1.6-.42-1.184-1.185l.159-.291A1.873 1.873 0 0 0 1.945 8.93l-.319-.094c-.835-.246-.835-1.428 0-1.674l.319-.094A1.873 1.873 0 0 0 3.06 4.377l-.16-.292c-.415-.764.42-1.6 1.185-1.184l.292.159a1.873 1.873 0 0 0 2.692-1.115l.094-.319z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-slash-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z"/>
          <path d="M11.354 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pencil-square" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M15.502 1.94a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .706L14.459 3.69l-2-2L13.502.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l1.293 1.293zm-1.75 2.456-2-2L4.939 9.21a.5.5 0 0 0-.121.196l-.805 2.414a.25.25 0 0 0 .316.316l2.414-.805a.5.5 0 0 0 .196-.12l6.813-6.814z"/>
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1 13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h11a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-6a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5H9a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chat-right-text" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M2 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v8a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h9.586a2 2 0 0 1 1.414.586l2 2V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2zm12-1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12.793a.5.5 0 0 1-.854.353l-2.853-2.853a1 1 0 0 0-.707-.293H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12z"/>
          <path d="M3 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h9a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3 6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h9a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-9A.5.5 0 0 1 3 6zm0 2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-sticky" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M2.5 1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 2.5v11A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 2.5 15h6.086a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.06-.44l4.915-4.914A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 15 8.586V2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 13.5 1h-11zM2 2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V8H9.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 8 9.5V14H2.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-11zm7 11.293V9.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4.293L9 13.793z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-circle-half" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1v14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 1 8 0a8 8 0 0 1 0 16z"/>
        </svg></a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <span id = "video-placeholder">
      
    </span>
    </div>

    <!--<div id = "video-controls-container">
      <button class = "controls">Skip backwards</button> <button class = "controls">skip forwards</button> <button class = "controls">Control</button> <button class = "controls">Control</button>
      </div>-->
</main>


<footer class = "navbar navbar-expand fixed-bottom">
  <div class = "container-fluid">
    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-outline-primary" id = "play-button">Play video</button>

    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "navbarCollapse">
      <span class = "navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0" id = "">
        <!--<div id = "scrub-bar">
        </div>-->
      </span>
      <form class = "d-flex">
        <button id = "placeholder">Trim</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

    <script src = "Interface/javascript/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey there thanks for this!  I greatly appreciate you taking the time to respond to this :) How can I retain the margin over the top and bottom of the midsection elements when the browser window is resized?    Was hoping to keep some margin, even with a smaller sized window.  Also with your proposal, some of the elements are now a bit funny looking (The upload button for example)  Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: You can't retain the margins as fixed margins because you want the height to shrink and grow with the browser window, and margin and buttons sizes both are part of the total height of the page.

I've given an example of how you could do it above, you can tweak it to suit your needs.

If my answer helped you, can you please award it? Or at least upvote.

Comment: I have done some additional changes & fixed the buttons after you posted, as they were a bit odd looking.  Thanks for also clarifying on the margins!  And I most certainly will upvote & award you as well (as soon as I can figure out how to :D) If your open to a more direct means of communication (Skype, email), & maybe working with me a bit further or giving me some pointers. I would most certainly be willing to compensate you for your time & guidance if your interested as well! :)  Thanks again

Comment: Adding onto my previous reply, I'm afraid I can not upvote your post as requested. Won't let me as I do not have enough reputation to do so. Sorry for any inconvenience(s) this may cause. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: No prob, I understand. With regards to more direct communication, let me know your Skype/email, I'll drop you a message.

Comment: You can find me on Skype under the username 'Raiden' looking forward to hearing from you! ( Just let me know who you are when reaching out :) )